# What should I back up before updating apache?

Tags: updates, apache2, backup

Which folders and files should I make copies of before updating to the latest version of Apache, in case something goes awry?

Answer (score 1):

I am curious to why you ask this because it should be the same files you backup during your regular backup. So what to backup should already be known. Personally I use a script that runs itself after I turn my machine on, when I turn it off and during my lunch break. I use `rsync` for it so it only backs up changed files. I lost count how many times I messed up deleting something that should not be deleted.

Question you need to ask yourself: What files did I change and add to get apache working and to have it serve me my website?

There are 2 directories to take note of:

- `/etc/apache2/`. It holds configurations and website settings. `apache.conf`. `http.conf`, `sites-enabled`, `sites-available`. Probably everything in there.
- the directory your document root is set to. The default would be `/var/www/html/`, otherwise you would need to backup to what you changed it to.